How can I export a gt table to Word while retaining formatting in RStudio?
I've generated a formatted table in RStudio using the gt package, and I'm ready to export it. My issue is that when I run the gtsave() function and specify that my output file is a .docx file, I successfully get an output, but the output retains none of the formatting I coded for:
"Successful" output:

I tried adding the webshot2 and rmarkdown packages to get the export to preserve formatting, and it started throwing an error
Code:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(gt)
library(webshot2)
library(rmarkdown)

sampletabledata<-read_csv('sampledata.csv')

gt_sampletabledata<-gt(sampletabledata)

gt_sampletabledata|>tab_header(title="Count of Households with Pets")%>%
  opt_align_table_header(align='left')%>%
  tab_spanner(label="Fiscal Year", columns=c(`15/16`,`16/17`,`17/18`,`18/19`,`19/20`,`20/21`,`21/22`,`22/23`,`23/24`))%>%
  tab_style(style=list(cell_text(color='#F76900',weight = 'bold')),locations=cells_column_labels())%>%
  tab_style(style=list(cell_text(color='#000E54',weight = 'bold')),locations=cells_body(col=1))%>%
  tab_style(style=list(cell_text(color='#F76900',weight = 'bold')),locations=cells_column_spanners())%>%
  opt_table_font(google_font(name='Aptos'))

gtsave(gt_sampletabledata, 'gt_sampledata.docx')

Error:
Unknown output format doc
Pandoc can convert to DOCX, but not to DOC.
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 22

This is the desired output (screenshot from RStudio Viewer):

This is the dataset used (for troubleshooting purposes):
structure(list(`Number of Pets in Household` = c("0", "1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "(Missing)", "Total"), `15/16` = c(1, 
446, 294, 42, 6, 5, 2, 0, 146, 942), `16/17` = c(0, 641, 574, 
82, 12, 3, 1, 0, 610, 1923), `17/18` = c(1, 799, 747, 112, 30, 
5, 1, 0, 1662, 3357), `18/19` = c(0, 805, 807, 67, 15, 6, 1, 
1, 2108, 3810), `19/20` = c(0, 1260, 787, 74, 19, 4, 3, 0, 1748, 
3895), `20/21` = c(1, 1510, 854, 102, 22, 8, 3, 0, 1387, 3887
), `21/22` = c(1, 1746, 971, 121, 19, 5, 1, 0, 1699, 4563), `22/23` = c(26, 
1531, 1064, 162, 42, 8, 4, 1, 4469, 7307), `23/24` = c(6, 445, 
300, 48, 7, 2, 0, 1, 810, 1619)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(`Number of Pets in Household` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `15/16` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `16/17` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `17/18` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `18/19` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `19/20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `20/21` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `21/22` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `22/23` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `23/24` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x000001317ba37ad0>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


Two things happening here: the formatted object has not be assigned to gt_sampletabledata; plus the output file type (DOCX) is not being recognised. For the latter, are the packages all up-to-date? What version of R? Posting the data will likely elicit more help.

I do believe all packages are up to date. For the former, can you explain more why the formatted object can't be assigned to gt_sampletabledata? Do I need to assign it to a new variable?

The table formats are not being "saved" at the end of the piped commands. Try changing last line to: opt_table_font(google_font(name='Aptos')) |> gt_sampletabledata

Appreciate the tweak! Unfortunately it threw a new error when I added that line:
Error in gt_sampletabledata :    The pipe operator requires a function call as RHS (<input>:9:48)

Sorry, the added pipe should have been a right assignment.

It worked! It still had a couple of formatting incongruencies, but it's a lot closer to the desired output now. Why does assigning it back to the original variable that was specified at the top of the dplyr code block work? It's kind of baffling to assign it back again when it was already assigned (not complaining because it works, just curious). Thanks a bunch!

With thanks to DavoOZ for the solve, what I was missing was saving the formats back to the original variable at the end of the dplyr piped code. Adding a right assignment pipe <- is the key. Here's the updated code:
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

sampletabledata<-read_csv('sampledata.csv')

gt_sampletabledata<-gt(sampletabledata) 

gt_sampletabledata <- gt_sampletabledata%>%
  tab_header(title="Count of Households with Pets")%>%
  opt_align_table_header(align='left')%>%
  tab_spanner(label="Fiscal Year", columns=c(`15/16`,`16/17`,`17/18`,`18/19`,`19/20`,`20/21`,`21/22`,`22/23`,`23/24`))%>%
  tab_style(style=list(cell_text(color='#F76900',weight = 'bold')),locations=cells_column_labels())%>%
  tab_style(style=list(cell_text(color='#000E54',weight = 'bold')),locations=cells_body(col=1))%>%
  tab_style(style=list(cell_text(color='#F76900',weight = 'bold')),locations=cells_column_spanners())%>%
  tab_options(table_body.vlines.color=NULL, table.border.left.color=NULL,table.border.right.color = NULL)%>%
  opt_table_font(google_font(name='Aptos'))-> gt_sampletabledata


gtsave(gt_sampletabledata,'gt_sampledata.docx')

This is the output (not perfect, but closer to what I wanted):Updated Output
